# Is "then" completely natural here to connect the sentences?

Tags: word-choice

*I didn't hear anything for a few months, so I assumed she wasn't interested. **Then** last week she called me to my surprise and asked if I would go out on another date with her.*

Is **then** completely natural here to connect the sentences?

Comment: I guess it is nicer to show the effort you already made, such as the definition/explanation and examples on dictionary or other trusted reference.

Comment: What's the difference between "Completely natural" and just regular "natural" here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's natural. The first sentence sets a background in the past for what follows. The word "then" moves us up to a more recent time frame.  The second sentence would be less natural in context without "then".